# Is there a commandline option to modify service properties?

Tags: windows, service, command-line

I'm working on a script, which should switch between two services: switch one on an the other off and vice versa.

In top of that, I would like to avoid both services being started at the same time, therefore I'm thinking of modifying the properties of the service: I would like to modify the startup type from automatic to disabled and vice versa.

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Are you asking about sc.exe or programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, using `sc`:

```
sc config Own_Server1 start=auto
sc config Own_Server2 start=disabled
```